# Disable the selected value in drop down menu

Tags: asp.net, sql, drop-down-menu

I have this drop down menu.It stores month, Jan-Dec. User can choose any value of the drop down menu but just one time only. Meaning, lets say previously he choose Jan, the next time if he logged in/ enter new record, he cannot choose Jan anymore or maybe remove the month permanently. Once he select the month, it will be store in session to other page. So, if you guys have any idea,suggestions, or plans, dont hesitate to leave ur answer here. Thank you.

Comment: [so] isn't really about ideas but problem solving, give us some code, describe problem, show your own effort on solving it...

Comment: it just a simple straight forward question. But if you dont see any efford of me on solving this prob, its ok. I shouldnt post this kind of prob bcause it doesnt looks like a prob to u. Bdw, thanks for stopping by.

Comment: Duplicate of.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527138/disable-remove-value-in-dropdown-menu-after-being-selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three working examples of what you're looking for:

Using jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/wLNZX/

With plain JavaScript:

http://jsfiddle.net/wLNZX/1/

Coded inline with the `<select>` tag:

http://jsfiddle.net/wLNZX/2/