# Disable/remove value in dropdown menu after being selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Just wanna ask u guys for help. I have this dropdown menu in my abc.aspx page. There, user will choose month and enter the expenses and prices in the textbox provided. It will be saved in session :

```
session["month"]= dropdownlist1.selectedvalue;
session["expense1"] - textbox1.text;
session["price1"] - textbox2.text;
server.transfer ("sdf.aspx");
```

In the next page, the entered data will be viewed in label:

```
Label1.Text = session ["month"].ToString();
Label2.Text = session ["expense1"].ToString();
Label3.Text = session ["price1"].ToString();
```

Ok, my question is, how can make the month in drop down menu can be selected only once? Lets say, if the user choose Febuary, next time if he login, he cant choose the febuary anymore. I have used this code:

```
asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" 
        onchange="if(this.value!='Please choose') this.disabled='true';" Font-Bold="True">
        <asp:ListItem>Please choose</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>January</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Febuary</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>March</asp:ListItem>
```

But the problem is when i chose March, in the next page it supposed to show March isnt it? But, it shows 'Please choose'. So, i really hope there's someone here can help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try the following:

**ASPX**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Please choose" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="January" Value="January"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="February" Value="February"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="March" Value="March"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**C#**

```
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Month"] != null)
        {
            if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue == Session["Month"])
            {
                DropDownList1.SelectedValue = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                Session["Month"] = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Make this is the ASPX and C# on your first page.

Comment: Hey, thank you for ur respond. Just wanna ask you, what to put  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Session["Month"] = "February"; //---> not very clear
            }
        }

Comment: I was using it for testing/simulating what you had. You do not need it. Can you let me know if the answer I gave answers your question?

Comment: No. in dropdownlist2,selectedvalue = string.empty; it gives me this error : only assignment,call,increament..ect can b used as a statemnt. Anything wrong?

Comment: make sure you copy the code from my ASPX and C# part exactly as it is i.e. DropDownList2.SelectedValue = string.Empty; and not DropDownList2,SelectedValue = string.Empty; (Notice the comma in your line)

Comment: Seany, it works fine bbut it still d same. It still accept the record from the same month. :(

Comment: I have modified the code in my original post based on what I think you are asking.

Comment: herm, it still d same. Okay, since this looks complicated to do, do u know how to replace the month, lets say if he choose april, then next time he log in, he choose april again, the exist record in db will be replaced if the month is same.

Comment: @dontshare I don't think that it is too complicated. I think you have not explained your problem, given enough code or asked a direct question. Can you look your original post and either re-phrase it and fix your question so it is more clear to everyone what you want. I think you need to use my code in your first page? Does this sort it?

Comment: Or, is the problem that when a user leaves your web site and returns at a later date that you do not want the month to be selectable on the first page? If that is the case you could look at storing the selected months information in a cookie and checking that when they hit the page.

Comment: Okay. I dont know how to explain it. Just the user can only choose any month except from the previous log in. Thats all. No month can be choose twice.

Comment: Ok, so you can't use the Session then! If a user logs-out the session is gone/cleared. You would need to store the selected value of the month in either a cookie or else in a database. What happens in your code when a user logs-out?

Comment: Does the .Abondon() part give you any clues as to what might happen when it is called and why you could not use it to set the value of a drop down? Why don't you post your full code?