# Replace records in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a table in db which stores username, month, expenses, and price. User will select month from dropdown menu. Any month. But lets say if he already select January before, then if he login and choose January again, the system will be replace the old records of January with the new one. My question is, how to replace in db if the user choose same month as before?

Thank you

Comment: What's your question?  Are you experiencing a problem with the code you posted?

Comment: after do some observations, users with high reputations are asking very politely ask the user if he/she not very clear with the question. Well, its not wrong to be polite. No offense.

Comment: Your post/questions are too vague. There is generally not enough code or information supplied with them. The most frustrating part is that when you are asked to supply more information or code you reply with some bizarre unhelpful comments. This is the third time you have asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527138/disable-remove-value-in-dropdown-menu-after-being-selected  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9512448/disable-the-selected-value-in-drop-down-menu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527933/replace-records-in-sql You have only marked 2 of 11 with answers too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand deleteCmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM ExpTab WHERE username = @name AND month = @mnth", conn);
        deleteCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        deleteCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Membership.GetUser().UserName);
        deleteCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mnth", Label1.Text);
        deleteCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into ExpTab (username,month,ex1,p1) Values (@name,@mnth,@ex1s,@p1s)", conn);

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Membership.GetUser().UserName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mnth", Label1.Text);
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: I would fire anyone writing this. Ever heads of SQL Server "update" command? Or Merge? Writing an Upsert sequence (Update or Insert) is beginner level. Delete/Insert is always bad - it has serious side effects.

Comment: I would guess this is in response to the gimme the codez attitude.

Comment: Ironically - according to relational theory anyway - a Delete/Insert is exactly what occurs when performing an update.

Answer (score 3):

Check as part of your query, and do an *update* instead of an *insert* if the month entry exists already:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from ExpTab where month = @mnth)
BEGIN
  Insert into ExpTab (username,month,ex1,p1) Values (@name,@mnth,@ex1s,@p1s)
END
ELSE
  Update ExpTab Set username = @name, ex1 = @ex1s, p1 = @p1s where month = @mnth
```